# A Python base class for a family of Postgres server manager classes

Tags: python, inheritance, postgresql, portability

I'm working on a repo the purpose of which is to **create and manage a local PostGIS server**. (PostGIS is a bit niche, but it boils down to a few extra **spatial** data types and built-in SQL function. With a couple of commands you can install these extensions on pretty much any **Postgres** database.)

My current workplace involves a mix of Linux and Windows; therefore, I'm always trying to make my code as **cross platform** as possible - although I much prefer Linux! **Inheritance** seemed like the best way of handling the different platforms. This code is the **base class**; there are child classes for Linux and Windows.

If it's helpful for me to do so, I'm more than happy to post code from the child classes.

```py
"""
This code defines an abstract BASE class from which Debian, Windows, etc child
classes can inherit.
"""

# Standard imports.
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import ClassVar
import warnings

# Non-standard imports.
import geopandas
import psycopg2
from geopandas import GeoDataFrame
from psycopg2.extensions import ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT
from psycopg2.extras import RealDictCursor
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

# Bespoke imports.
from ufo_utils import os_codes

# Local imports.
from .package_utils import DefaultsGenerator
if __package__:
    from . import constants
else:
    import constants

# Local constants.
EXAMPLE_TABLE_NAME_BUILDINGS = \
    constants.EXAMPLE_TABLE_NAME_STEM+constants.BUILDINGS_LAYER_KEY
EXAMPLE_TABLE_NAME_VIEWS = \
    constants.EXAMPLE_TABLE_NAME_STEM+constants.VIEWS_LAYER_KEY
DEF_GEN = DefaultsGenerator()

##############
# MAIN CLASS #
##############

@dataclass
class PostGISServitorBase:
    """ The main class. """
    # Class attributes.
    DEF_GEN: ClassVar[DefaultsGenerator] = DEF_GEN
    PATH_TO_CONFIGS_FILE: ClassVar[str] = constants.PATH_TO_CONFIGS_FILE
    PLATFORM: ClassVar[str] = os_codes.OTHER

    # Object attributes.
    username: str = DEF_GEN.get_default("username")
    password: str = DEF_GEN.get_default("password")
    database_name: str = DEF_GEN.get_default("database_name")
    host: str = DEF_GEN.get_default("host")
    port: int = DEF_GEN.get_default("port")

    def set_from_dict(self, mapping):
        """ Set the fields of this class from a dictionary, ignoring any keys
        which don't fit. """
        for key, value in mapping.items():
            if hasattr(self, key) and value is not None:
                if key.isupper():
                    warnings.warn(
                        "You are attempting to alter a what looks a class "+
                        "attribute, "+
                        key+
                        ". I am going to pretend that you never asked me to "+
                        "do this."
                    )
                else:
                    setattr(self, key, value)

    def make_host(self):
        """ Turn this device into the HOST device for our database. """
        self.install_3rd_party()
        self.create_local_server()
        self.create_database()

    def run_and_commit_master(self, query, params=None):
        """ Run a given non-fetch query against the MASTER database. """
        connection = \
            psycopg2.connect(
                user=self.username,
                password=self.password,
                host=self.host,
                port=self.port,
                database=constants.MAIN_POSTGRES_DATABASE_NAME
            )
        connection.set_isolation_level(ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT)
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        if params:
            cursor.execute(query, params=params)
        else:
            cursor.execute(query)
        connection.commit()
        cursor.close()
        connection.close()

    def create_database(self):
        """ Create our PostGIS database. """
        self.run_and_commit_master("CREATE DATABASE "+self.database_name+";")
        self.run_and_commit(constants.INSTALL_POSTGIS_QUERY)
        self.upload_example_geodataframe()

    def drop_database(self):
        """ Drop our PostGIS database. """
        query = (
            "DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS "+
            self.database_name+" "+
            "WITH (FORCE);" # Little bit hacky, but gets the job done.
        )
        self.run_and_commit_master(query)

    def make_connection(self):
        """ Create a connection object for our database. """
        result = \
            psycopg2.connect(
                user=self.username,
                password=self.password,
                host=self.host,
                port=self.port,
                database=self.database_name
            )
        return result

    def run_and_commit(self, query, params=None):
        """ Run a given non-fetch query against our database. """
        connection = self.make_connection()
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        if params:
            cursor.execute(query, params)
        else:
            cursor.execute(query)
        connection.commit()
        cursor.close()
        connection.close()

    def run_and_commit_many(self, query_params_pairs):
        """ Run SEVERAL non-fetch queries against our database. """
        connection = self.make_connection()
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        for pair in query_params_pairs:
            query = pair[0]
            params = pair[0]
            if params:
                cursor.execute(query, params)
            else:
                cursor.execute(query)
        connection.commit()
        cursor.close()
        connection.close()

    def fetch(self, query, params=None):
        """ Fetch data from the database, using a query. """
        connection = self.make_connection()
        cursor = connection.cursor(cursor_factory=RealDictCursor)
        if params:
            cursor.execute(query, params)
        else:
            cursor.execute(query)
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        cursor.close()
        connection.close()
        return result

    def run_sql_script(self, path_to):
        """ Run a given SQL script against our database. """
        with open(path_to, "r") as sql_file:
            sql_code = sql_file.read()
            self.run_and_commit(sql_code)

    def get_connection_string(self):
        """ Generate and return a database string. """
        result = (
            "postgresql://"+
            self.username+
            ":"+
            self.password+
            "@"+
            self.host+
            ":"+
            str(self.port)+
            "/"+
            self.database_name
        )
        return result

    def get_engine_obj(self):
        """ Generate and return a GeoAlchemy engine object. """
        connection_string = self.get_connection_string()
        result = create_engine(connection_string)
        return result

    def make_geodataframe_from_query(
            self,
            query,
            geometry_column_name="geometry",
            co_ref_sys=None,
            index_column=None
        ):
        """ Run a query against the database, and put the results into a
        GeoDataFrame object. """
        engine = self.get_engine_obj()
        result = \
            GeoDataFrame.from_postgis(
                query,
                engine,
                geom_col=geometry_column_name,
                crs=co_ref_sys,
                index_col=index_column
            )
        return result

    def upload_geodataframe(
            self,
            geodataframe,
            table_name,
            schema=None,
            if_exists="append",
            index=False,
            index_label=None
        ):
        """ Upload a given GeoDataFrame object to the database as an entirely
        new table. """
        engine = self.get_engine_obj()
        geodataframe.to_postgis(
            table_name,
            engine,
            schema=schema,
            if_exists=if_exists,
            index=index,
            index_label=index_label
        )

    def upload_example_geodataframe(self):
        """ Read in an example GeoDataFrame object from a file, and upload it
        to the database as its own table. """
        geodataframe_buildings = \
            geopandas.read_file(
                constants.PATH_TO_EXAMPLE_GEODATAFRAME,
                layer=constants.BUILDINGS_LAYER_KEY
            )
        geodataframe_views = \
            geopandas.read_file(
                constants.PATH_TO_EXAMPLE_GEODATAFRAME,
                layer=constants.VIEWS_LAYER_KEY
            )
        self.upload_geodataframe(
            geodataframe_buildings, constants.EXAMPLE_TABLE_NAME_BUILDINGS
        )
        self.upload_geodataframe(
            geodataframe_views, constants.EXAMPLE_TABLE_NAME_VIEWS
        )
```